# Nested structure: List of lists of tuples python

Tags: python, list, nested, tuples

I am trying to deal with a nested structure that looks like this:

```
list_of_lists= [[("aaa"),("bbb")],[("ccc"),("ddd")],[("eee"),("fff")]]
```

and I need to add a column of elements that looks like this:

```
 column_to_add = ["string1", "string2", "string3"]
```

The final result should look like this:

```
[[("aaa", "string1"),("bbb", "string1")],[("ccc", "string2"),("ddd", "string2")],[("eee", "string3"),("fff", "string3")]]
```

I have tried something like this:

```
result= []
for internal_list in list_of_lists:
    for tuple in internal_list:
        for z in tuple:
            for new_string in column_to_add:
                kk=list(tuple)
                result = tuple.append(new_string)
```

But it does not seem to work at all.
Can anyone help me?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: your logic is wrong..for *each* tuple you are looping through `column_to_add`. You want to match each index of `internal_list` to the matching index of `column_to_add`. Zipa's answer does this through `enumerate` which provides an index to work with. Rakesh's answer uses `zip` which zips up the two lists where he unpacks and uses them. Both use list comprehension which is similar to a for loop appending items to initial empty list

Comment: Now it's way clearer, so if I understood correctly using zip or enumerate is completely equivalent. Right?

Comment: They both create iterators (yield on the fly) objects, the objects created are slightly different though, one (zip) is a tuple on the actual matching elements, one is a (index, item) tuple leaving you free to use the index however you like. I prefer enumerate in this case as the code is more explicit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your data looks like this:

```
list_of_lists= [[("aaa", ),("bbb", )],[("ccc", ),("ddd", )],[("eee", ),("fff", )]]
```

You should use:

```
[[y + (column_to_add[i], ) for y in x] for i, x in enumerate(list_of_lists)]
```

This produces:

```
#[[('aaa', 'string1'), ('bbb', 'string1')],
# [('ccc', 'string2'), ('ddd', 'string2')],
# [('eee', 'string3'), ('fff', 'string3')]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `zip` and a nested list comprehension

**Ex:**

```
list_of_lists= [[("aaa"),("bbb")],[("ccc"),("ddd")],[("eee"),("fff")]]
column_to_add = ["string1", "string2", "string3"]

print([[(i, n) for i in m] for m,n in zip(list_of_lists, column_to_add)])
```

**Output:**

```
[[('aaa', 'string1'), ('bbb', 'string1')],
 [('ccc', 'string2'), ('ddd', 'string2')],
 [('eee', 'string3'), ('fff', 'string3')]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list_of_lists= [[("aaa"),("bbb")],[("ccc"),("ddd")],[("eee"),("fff")]]
column_to_add = ["string1", "string2", "string3"]
res  = list(map(lambda x,y: [(i,y) for i in x], list_of_lists, column_to_add))
print(res)
```

output

```
[
   [('aaa', 'string1'), ('bbb', 'string1')], 
   [('ccc', 'string2'), ('ddd', 'string2')], 
   [('eee', 'string3'), ('fff', 'string3')]
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need something likes `zip()`.

First, keep `(aaa, bbb)` and `string1` in pair.

```py
a = [[("aaa"),("bbb")],[("ccc"),("ddd")],[("eee"),("fff")]]
b = ["string1", "string2", "string3"]
zipped_data = list(zip(a, b))

# zipped_data = [(['aaa', 'bbb'], 'string1'), (['ccc', 'ddd'], 'string2'), (['eee', 'fff'], 'string3')]
```

Then, let `string1` make pair with each iterator of the tuple `(aaa, bbb)`.

```py
new_list = []
for u in zipped_data:
    new_list.append([(u[0][0], u[1]), (u[0][1], u[1])])
print(new_list)
```

The output is

```
[[('aaa', 'string1'), ('bbb', 'string1')], [('ccc', 'string2'), ('ddd', 'string2')], [('eee', 'string3'), ('fff', 'string3')]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehensions.

```
lst = [[("aaa",), ("bbb",)], [("ccc",), ("ddd",)], [("eee",), ("fff",)]]
col = ["string1", "string2", "string3"]

result = [[(*tup, col[i]) for tup in lst[i]] for i in range(len(lst))]
```

Output:

```
[[('aaa', 'string1'), ('bbb', 'string1')], [('ccc', 'string2'), ('ddd', 'string2')], [('eee', 'string3'), ('fff', 'string3')]]
```

**Upd.**

It could be more "safe" to use length of `col` as limit of range.

```
result = [[(*tup, col[i]) for tup in lst[i]] for i in range(len(col))]
```